# Splitting a String in Java throws PatternSyntaxException

Tags: java, android, regex, split

I want to split a String in Android using Java. I have done this before but now I get this exception

```
11-20 17:57:37.665: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25423): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN near index 1:
11-20 17:57:37.665: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25423): (
11-20 17:57:37.665: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25423):  ^
```

My string is like

```
String mystring=  "iamhere(32)";
```

and I want to keep only the "iamhere".

I split it using

```
String[] seperation = mystring.Split("(");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried to use mystring.Split("\\("); ?

Comment: I get an error when i use ("\(") i tried using ("\\(") and got it right :)

Comment: @user: java considers " ( "this as part of regular expression. try to use backslash to escape  example :  mystring.split("\\(");

Answer (score 7):

**("\(")** would be an invalid escape sequence. To escape the meaning of **"("** we should be using **"\\"** in java.

```
    String mystring = "iamhere(32)";
    String[] sep = mystring.split("\\(");
    System.out.println("String after split ",sep[0]+" ");
```